# Can I call cubit from another cubit?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-state, cubit, flutter-cubit

I'm working on an application that uses cubits to manage the state.
Very often when I need to make an API request I need to get my current localization (handle possible exceptions) and then send it to backend. So I guess I should use cubit for the requests and for getting my current localization.

My question is how should I handle that? Can I somehow call `gpsLocalizationCubit` from another cubit? Should I call `gpsLocalizationCubit` and on success call `requestCubit` with the use of bloc listener? But then how should I manage loading screen that should be visible for both getting localization and API request?
Another problem is that I have multiple similar requests (that need to use current localization) in a single view.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to communicate between Blocs or Cubits is to pass their stream as a parameter. In your cas you could implement something like that:

```
class LocationCubit extends Cubit<LocationData> {
  ...
}

class SomeCubit extends Cubit<SomeState> {
  final StreamSubscription _locationSubscription;

  SomeCubit({required Stream<LocationData> locationStream}) {
    _locationSubscription = locationStream.listen((locationData) {
      // update your state with the new location or do something
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _locationData.cancel();
    super.close();
  }
}

// Where you create your Cubits:
final locationCubit = LocationCubit();
final myCubit = SomeCubit(locationStream: locationCubit.stream);
```

That way you will not have any direct dependency between your Cubit classes.

An other way could be to listen for location changes by using the location package https://pub.dev/packages/location in some kind of manager. This manager could be a singleton that you inject with GetIt for example, so you can mock it in your tests.